# Traefik & Keycloak: error SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, keycloak, traefik

I use an `HAProxy` to redirect all requests from 80 port to a 443 and using a NodePort to enter on a `traefik-ingress-controller` (v1.6.6, inside a Kubernetes cluster).

Here the `HAProxy.conf`:

```
frontend http-frontend                                                                                                               
       bind *:80                                                                                                                     
       reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http                                                                                               
       default_backend http_app                                                                                                      

frontend https-frontend                                                                                                             
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/my-cert.pem                                                                   
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https                                                                                            
        default_backend traefik_app                                                                                                 

backend http_app                                                                                                                    
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }                                                                                        

backend traefik_app                                                                                                             
    server traefik localhost:30010 check
```

Every application running on my Kubernetes cluster has an Ingress.

Among them I have a Keycloak pod (v4.1.0, for the authentication) with this ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: login.myapp.it
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```

Here a picture:

[image]

When I connect to https://login.myapp.it/auth/admin/ I get redirected to
https://login.myapp.it:80/auth/admin/master/console/ (note the port 80) and I received an `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` error.

Someone has some hints for this redirect issue with keycloak behind proxy?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using the following traefik annotation:

**traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "true"**

that forwards client **Host** header to the backend.

Here a complete ingress example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: login.myapp.it
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```

In alternative I may have added to **haproxy.cfg** the following:

**reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing your TLS certs on your ingress:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system create secret tls your-k8s-tls-secret --key=tls.key --cert=tls.crt
```

Then:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: your-k8s-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: login.myapp.it
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: My `cert.pem` is haproxy-side. I'll try your suggestion anyway, but I think the problem is more related with the keycloak redirection.

Comment: Yeah could be. Is keycloak also seving on TLS? Do you have certs for that?